# How "p4 changes" work on deleted path

Tags: perforce, changelist

Suppose the following event happen in chronicle order.

1. A file get deleted on path **'//depot/Tool/Web/test.html'** in changelist 123
2. The folder, which only contain that file, get deleted along with the file, so the resulted directory structure is **'//depot/Tool/...'**
3. At this time, when we issue **'p4 changes //depot/Tool/Web/...'**, will we get an error?
4. Then a file was added to the path that was previously deleted: **'//depot/Tool/Web/verify.css'** in changelist 456
5. At this time, when we issue **'p4 changes //depot/Tool/Web/...'** again, will the changelist 123 appear in the search result?

I am asking this because I want to know how Perforce record the changelist/file/path information.

Comment: You can download a free trial version of Perforce and try out these queries yourself; this will help you feel more comfortable with the operation of the server.

Comment: That's a very practical suggestion, I should definitely build a test environment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, changelist 123 will appear at both of the points where you run "p4 changes"; Perforce keeps a complete history of all files and directories.

The change information is stored in metadata separate from the files themselves.